# Can we use alias in merge statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-merge

```
Merge into exchangeuplift up 
using (select up. Rowid row_id, up.forcedcharge/evcal.totalnotion)
       from exchange evcal 
       join exchangeuplift up 
       on evcal.exchangename = up.exchangename
       and up.isactive = 1 
       and up.forcedcharge <> 0 evcal.totalnotion <> 0 ) src 
       on (up.rowid = src.row_id) 
when matched then 
    update set forcedchargepro = (src.forcecharge/ evcal.totalnotion)
```

Error: ora-00904 "evcal.totalnotion" Invalid identifier

Getting error at last line, can we use divide in set conditions

Comment: Your code has several error before you hit that one; you have an extra `)` and missing an `and` I think, but hard to be sure. Please post your actual code, and [format it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Even then I'm not sure what you're asking; or why - you already use an alias for `row_id`? Your `set` clause refers to `evcal.totalnotion` but `evcal` is only in scope within the `using()` clause, and `src.forcecharge` but the `src` block doesn't have that as an alias. So not clear if you want original values or just the result of the calculation (which does need a column alias).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several errors that seem to be a mix of typos or transcription mistakes posting it, but it looks like you might be trying to do:

```
merge into exchangeuplift up
using (
  select up.rowid row_id,
    up.forcedcharge / evcal.totalnotion result
  from exchange evcal
  join exchangeuplift up
  on evcal.exchangename = up.exchangename
  and up.isactive = 1
  and up.forcedcharge <> 0
  and evcal.totalnotion <> 0
) src
on (up.rowid = src.row_id)
when matched then update
  set forcedchargepro = src.result
```

I've given the result of the calculation within the `using` clause the alias `result`, and then referred to that in the `set` clause. You can't refer to columns from `evcal` or the inner `up` in that clause.

Looking at `exchangeuplift` again in the `using` clause seems a bit redundant though; this might also work:

```
merge into exchangeuplift up
using exchange src
on (up.exchangename = src.exchangename)
when matched then update
  set up.forcedchargepro = up.forcedcharge / src.totalnotion
  where up.isactive = 1
  and up.forcedcharge <> 0
  and src.totalnotion <> 0
```

or maybe:

```
merge into exchangeuplift up
using exchange src
on (up.exchangename = src.exchangename
  and up.isactive = 1
  and up.forcedcharge <> 0
)
when matched then update
  set up.forcedchargepro = up.forcedcharge / src.totalnotion
  where src.totalnotion <> 0
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=788addb366712f91d6a1940f4ea7f777) with made-up data based on what the code seems to be doing, as you didn't provide data or expected results.